# angular Scope variable is not binding in to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

i am creating hidden iframe for printing some data, but my code is not working properly, i want to show some data in that iframe by using angular scope variable bellow is my code.

```
        // print attached contract documnet
    function print(imageData) {
        var hiddenFrame = $('<iframe style="display: none"></iframe>').appendTo('body')[0];
        hiddenFrame.contentWindow.printAndRemove = function () {
            hiddenFrame.contentWindow.print();
            $(hiddenFrame).remove();
        };

        $scope.testObj = 'testing';
        var element = $compile('<div> {{testObj}} </div>')($scope);
        // var element = $compile($('<div> <img ng-src="{{ vm.contractDetails.contractAttachment.imageSRC }}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img-height " style="height:500px;cursor:pointer;" /> </div>'))(printScope);


        var htmlDocument = "<!doctype html>" +
            "<html>" +
            '<body onload="printAndRemove();">' +
            element.html() +
            '</body>' +
            "</html>";
        var doc = hiddenFrame.contentWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");
        doc.write(htmlDocument);
        doc.close();
    }
```

then output is not proper
[image: print output]

`$scope.testObj` is not binding properly.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to show some data in that iframe by using angular scope
>   variable

#### Short answer

You **cannot** pass `$scope` to iframe regards to your configuration.

From image, angular didn't load inside iframe

**[EDIT 1]**

If you want to pass base64 image to iframe you don't need angular.

Just call:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,BINARY_DATA"></iframe>
```

If you want to use `ng-src` instead, to get rid of cross domain problem use `$sce` service:

```
<iframe  ng-src="{{someStuff}}"></iframe>

$scope.someFrame= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.yourURL.com");
```

**[EDIT 2]**

```
 <iframe src="{{value}}"> </iframe>
```

*Controller*

```
app.controller('ctrlRead', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.value= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("data:image/gif;base64,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");    
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b9vspwL/)</kbd>

Comment: i want to pass base64 image to that iframe can you help me with any example

Comment: @Developerzzz why not: `<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,BASE64_DATA"></iframe>`

Comment: <iframe src="vm.contractDetails.contractAttachment.imageSRC"></iframe> its throwing error Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-3OhP26JdEsfg9Rve2efgdPuBHAzVr+ns7nzZ7A70s1w='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: @Developerzzz see EDIT 2

Answer (score 0):

instead writing

```
var doc = hiddenFrame.contentWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");
doc.write(htmlDocument);
doc.close();
```

Use  [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
$scope.myHtml  = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.html);
```

In the `hiddenFrame`,add one placeHolder variable `{{myHtml}}`.

It will Worke.